# How to create adjacency list with these attributes (in a class)

Tags: python

```
class Vertex:  # vertex = node
def __init__(self, node):
    self.id = node
    self.adjacent = {}

def __str__(self):

    return str(self.id) + ' adjacent: ' + str([x.id for x in self.adjacent])
```

I am not sure how to create an adj list!

I tried a bunch of things but I usually get an error which looks something like:

> > bound<method vertex

( Sorry, I'm not getting this error anymore so I'm not entirely sure what it was )

I'm very stuck so any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: *not getting this error anymor* - so what's the current error?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest No clue what to try now.

Comment: what `adjacent` should contain? Other `Vertex ` ? Where is the code that adds something to `adjacent` ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the below is what you are looking for

```
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self, node):
        self.id = node
        self.adjacent = []

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + ' adjacent: ' + str([x.id for x in self.adjacent])


v1 = Vertex('12')
v1.adjacent.append(Vertex('122'))
v1.adjacent.append(Vertex('123'))

print(v1)
```

output

```
12 adjacent: ['122', '123']
```